# Why is `2 + x = 7` valid Haskell?

Tags: haskell

When I try to compile

```
main = putStrLn $ show x where
    2 + x = 7
```

GHC complains

```
error: Variable not in scope: x
  |
1 | main = putStrLn $ show x
  |                        ^
```

So it seems that `2 + x = 7` is by itself syntactically valid, although it doesn't actually define `x`. But why is it so?

Comment: Haskell often reports first fatal error,  only. Put a digit where the first out-of-scope `x` is to see additional errors, that is, `x` out of scope

Comment: It gets better. For example, `let 1+1 = 3 in 1+1`.

Comment: @Alec Indeed! Even better, `let 1+1=3 in 1+1` evaluates to `3` (not `2`), while `let 2=3 in 2` evaluates to `2` (not `3`). And, in ancient Haskell, `let x+2=7 in x` used to evaluate to `5`, unlike `let 2+x=7 in x` (fortunately, this is no longer the case.)

Comment: @chi I thought n+k patterns needed brackets, or is that not the case?

Comment: @Potato44 Yes, I think you are right. They have been removed from Haskell a long time ago, so I forgot how these precisely worked.

Comment: @chi They still exist in GHC, you just need to turn on `-XNPlusKPatterns`.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

It is valid because it defines `+` instead.

```
main = print (3 + 4)
   where -- silly redefinition of `+` follows
   0 + y = y
   x + y = x * ((x-1) + y)
```

Above, the Prelude `(+)` function is shadowed by a local binding. The result will be `24`, not `7`, consequently.

Turning on warnings should point out the dangerous shadowing.

```
<interactive>:11:6: warning: [-Wname-shadowing]
    This binding for ‘+’ shadows the existing binding
```

Answer (score 38):

You're defining a local function called `+`.

`2 + x = 7` is equivalent to `(+) 2 x = 7`, which is equivalent to

```
(+) y x | y == 2 = 7
```

`x` is an (unused) parameter, and the function is only defined if the first argument is `2`. That's not very useful, but it explains why `x` is not visible outside.